# Laravel & Vue js MPA, go back to previous needs to reload?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, multi-page-application

**Issue**

i'm currently making an application using laravel and vue js, but unlike the common implementation of vue js which is SPA, I'm trying to make the application in MPA. However, I just realized when I go back to previous page the whole page is reloaded, so the whole page is refreshed and the scroll position is back to the top of the page. This does not happen if I make it in pure blade (no vue js). This is very annoying in my case since I'm making infinite scrolling product list page and product detail page. It felt like a joke when the user want to go back to the product list after he sees the product detail, but the list is refreshed and the scroll position is on the top of the page (literally like a new page).

All of the page uses this blade layout

**productlist.blade.php** and **productdetail.blade.php**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>/* VueJs here */</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">//all element and vue component is inside here//</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

I have searched and browsed everywhere, yet i got nothing. I really hope someone can help me and give some advice to this matter since it's very hard to find discussions about laravel + vue js in MPA style.

Comment: While you are writing an MPA you should treat your search page as an SPA and retain a history of all user interactions with the page (that do not cause a page refresh). Then you will have all the information you need to reconstruct the page in the URL when you back. You will have to reload everything that needs reloading though

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    // return desired position
  }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.